# How to redirect and store data for the request after the redirect

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am trying to redirect the user to the login page with errors and a flash message.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
return $this->container->view->render($response,'admin/partials/login.twig',['errorss'=>$errors]);
```

But I want to redirect to the login page, while still having the errror messages and the flash message. I tried this way but does not work:

```
$this->container->flash->addMessage('fail',"Please preview the errors and login again."); 
return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('admin.login',['errors'=>$errors]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already used [`slim/flash`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash), but then you did this:

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('admin.login',['errors'=>$errors]));
```

which is not correct. The second parameter on the `Router#pathFor()` method is not for data to use after the redirect

> The router’s pathFor() method accepts two arguments:
>
> 1. The route name
> 2. Associative array of route pattern placeholders and replacement values

<sup>Source (http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)</sup>

So you can set placeholders like `profile/{name}` with the second parameter.

Now you need to add your errors all together to the [`slim/flash`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash)`.

I'm expaining this on the modified [Usage Guide of slim/flash](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Flash)

```
// can be 'get', 'post' or any other method
$app->get('/foo', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    // do something to get errors
    $errors = ['first error', 'second error'];

    // store messages for next request
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        $this->flash->addMessage('error', $error);
    }

    // Redirect
    return $res->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', $this->router->pathFor('bar'));
});

$app->get('/bar', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Get flash messages from previous request
    $errors = $this->flash->getMessage('error');

    // $errors is now ['first error', 'second error']

    // render view
    $this->view->render($response, 'admin/partials/login.twig', ['errors' => $errors]);
})->setName('bar');
```

Comment: Thank you, @jmattheis, I did have a look at Slim documentation but could not understand as I was scanning redirection including data (Learnt that I should avoid scanning only).But now I understood the way it works..thanks again :)  ..