# $response->withRedirect Does not show data that has been pass to the slim twig template engine

Tags: php, twig, slim, slim-3

I am trying to get the data(`$errors`) from the Array I pass into my slim\twig template using

`$response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor($event->getRoute(),$errors ))`,

but when I do a twig {{dump()}} i get null,

However if I do "`return $this->view->render($response,$event->getRoute(),$errors);`" and then dump it works I get the data i need.

I am wondering how to do it with the $response->withRedirect in slim3.

I looked around The slim\twig github (https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) but I couldn't find the document on how to pass The array over to twig using the `$response->withRedirect` or for my insanity is it just perfectly fine using `$this->view->render`

my slim 3 view setup is

```
$container['view']=function($container){
    $view =  new \Slim\Views\Twig('../app/Views',['cache' => false,'debug' => true]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container->router, 
        $container->request->getUri()
        ));

        $view->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
    return $view;
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect and store data for the request after the redirect in Slim 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656208/how-to-redirect-and-store-data-for-the-request-after-the-redirect-in-slim-3)

Comment: Thanks , that cleared things up for me.